# Adding Dependency Management to an Existing Java Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, dependency-management, ivy

I'm working on upgrading a legacy Java project to be compatible with jboss wildfly. As part of that process, I'm replacing our old system of managing dependencies (manually scanning for jars in a folder) with an automated system.

My first thought was to use maven, which worked well initially. The maven plugin for eclipse was able to scan my project and create a pom with most of the required dependencies. That works fine for compiling and running with eclipse, but production deployment uses an ant build script. I looked into maven-ant-resolver ( https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/index.html ) but as far as I can tell that project doesn't have a way to add dependencies to the classpath, the best it can do is bundle them into a jar.

The other option I looked at was Ivy. It seems better suited to integration with ant. Unfortunately, the tooling for ivy seems primitive compared to maven. From what I can tell, there is no option to generate the dependency file (ivy.xml) from an existing project. With the number of dependencies I'm dealing with, especially from jboss, creating the dependency xml from scratch is not a realistic option.

What are my options for solving this problem? Is there a way to do what I want with maven or ivy that I'm not seeing? Is there another dependency management tool out there that offers all the features I need?

Comment: I don't see the advantage of building _locally_ with Maven, if the build server builds with _Ant_.

Answer (score 0):

The [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)is what i can recommend for likely usecases. Not sure if it suits you though.

In a nutshell:
You can pack folders, jars, resources, dependencies, whatever into a jar for production deployment. This jar is packaged with the, from maven-assembly-plugin internally used and thus not needed to be referenced explicitly, [`maven-archiver-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) which also stores a MANIFEST.MF with the classpath in it (not by default but with few codes of tweaking).

Useful to know though: Maven allows you to quite easily create own Plugins that completely do what you want. If its just a file with the stored classpath, this could be a clean solution.